# SDL window closes immediately when using an std::variant or std::optional

Tags: c++, sdl, option-type, variant

I'm trying to create a simple renderer for an SDL2 application, and thought I would try to wrap the `SDL_*` resources in `unique_ptr` with their `SDL_Destroy*` functions as deleters, as well as an interface for creating that renderer that could handle the cases where it fails gracefully with an `std::variant` or an `std::optional`, i.e.:

My SDL renderer is a simple class with a boolean and a unique_ptr to a window, as such:

```
using SDLWindowUptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, std::function<void(SDL_Window*)>>;

template <Value, Error>
using either = std::variant<Value, Error>;

enum class SDLRendererError {
    SDLInitFailed, WindowCreationFailed
};

class SDLRenderer {
public:
static either<SDLRenderer, SDLRendererError> createRenderer();

private:
    explicit SDLRenderer(SDLWindowUptr window):
    _isRunning{false},
    _window{std::move(window)} 
    {}

public: // Allow moves, forbid copies
    SDLRenderer(const SDLRenderer& other) = delete;
    SDLRenderer(SDLRenderer&& other) = default;
    SDLRenderer& operator=(const SDLRenderer& other) = delete;
    SDLRenderer& operator=(SDLRenderer&& other) = default;

public:
    int run();
private:
    bool          _isRunning;
    SDLWindowUptr _window;
};
```

I simply init this class in the factory method by initializing the SDL with `SDL_INIT_VIDEO`, then create an SDL_Window which I move into the renderer class if it has been created successfully:

```
either<SDLRenderer, SDLRendererError> SDLRenderer::createRenderer() {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        return SDLRendererError:SDLInitFailed;
    }

    auto windowUptr = SDLWindowUptr{
        SDL_CreateWindow("Title",
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                         1280, 768,
                         SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE),
        SDL_DestroyWindow
    };

    if (!windowUptr) {
         return SDLRendererError::WindowCreationFailed;
    }

    return SDLRenderer{std::move(windowUptr)};
}
```

And in my main:

```
auto result = SDLRenderer::createRenderer();

if (std::holds_alternative<SDLRenderer>(result) {
    auto& renderer = std::get<SDLRenderer>(result);
    return renderer.run();
}
```

The SDL initialization completes successfully, as does the window creation.

Now this code actually yields an application where the window opens then closes instantly, and the main loop keeps running (it's only checking `SDL_PollEvent` and that's it), while `SDL_GetError` keeps spouting the same error message:

> The event system has been shut down

Here's the code for the main loop:

```
int SDLRenderer::run()
{
    auto event = SDL_Event{};
    _isRunning = true;

    // Main loop
    while(_isRunning) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            onEvent(&event);
        }
        std::cout << "[Loop] SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";

        SDL_Delay(200);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything runs fine if I don't use a variant (or an optional with exactly the same usage) in the process, with exactly the same initialization code on the SDL side.

What am I missing about variants and optionals, or maybe about my code that actually causes an issue when used inside a variant/optional?

Comment: Have you inited the VIDEO-subsystem via https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlinitsubsystem.html

Comment: @KimKulling I'm using SDL2 (I should probably mention it). And the initialization code is exactly the same for both approaches with and without variants. And it works in the latter case, but not in the former.

Comment: I just copy&pasted from an older version.